# react + material-ui 1.0 can table be disabled?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Adding disabled={true} to Table or TableBody or TableRow does not seem to disable table? Using https://codesandbox.io/s/n5wy74w8vl to test this.

Answer (score 0):

looking at html the Table class is an html table underneath and that does not have disabled attribute